# No provider for TabsPage in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

When running `ionic serve` I am getting an error in the browser `No Provider for TabsPage`.

The TabsPage is listed in the `app.module.ts`file:

```js
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { CalendarPage } from '../pages/calendar/calendar';
import { NewsPage } from '../pages/news/news';
import { SettingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal';
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version';
import { Calendar } from '@ionic-native/calendar';
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { SecureStorage } from '@ionic-native/secure-storage';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';



import { CalendarProvider } from '../providers/calendar/calendar';
import { SettingsProvider } from '../providers/settings/settings';
import { ConnectivityProvider } from '../providers/connectivity/connectivity';
import { NewsProvider } from '../providers/news/news';
import { CommonFunctionsProvider } from '../providers/common-functions/common-functions';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    CalendarPage,
    NewsPage,
    SettingsPage,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    CalendarPage,
    NewsPage,
    SettingsPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    OneSignal,
    AppVersion,
    Calendar,
    GoogleAnalytics,
    InAppBrowser,
    SecureStorage,
    Toast,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    SettingsProvider,
    CalendarProvider,
    ConnectivityProvider,
    NewsProvider,
    CommonFunctionsProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Are you injecting `TabsPage` in a constructor somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a page this error occurs, when you initialize this specific page in another like so:

```
constructor (public tabs: TabsPage) {}
```

If you have a provider that you want to initialize in a constructor, you need to declare it in the `app.module.ts` under `providers: []`.

Comment: how would you go about initializing a specific page in another page?  Is there a way?

Comment: @ShawnVarughese I think this is another topic, maybe consider to open a new question for this.